# Permission denied after trying to create mysqldump, even after creating .my.cnf file

Tags: permissions, mysql, backup

I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIIRuDtG1yI&list=PLtK75qxsQaMLZSo7KL-PmiRarU7hrpnwK&index=48) to create a simple mysqldump under my user directory. I have already made a configuration `.my.cnf` file for it in my root directory with password and created a folder to place the dump under my user directory. I can log into mysql fine as root.

I try to do the command there. It returns an error saying permission denied with the command I used. Keep in mind I haven't tried to create a database manually as I assumed the sql dump also creates the database if none existed.

this is the command I'm using...

```
sudo mysqldump --add-drop-table --databases myDatabaseName > /home/username/$(/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).sql.bak
```

Comment: *"It doesn't output anything"* ... where did you see the message `Permission denied` as shown in the title of the question?

Comment: The message occurs just after I use the command to create the mysqldump. It doesn't say anything else other than return the error from bash.

Comment: Please show the exact error, precisely as displayed.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot here is the error... `bash: /home/jordan/tutorialinux/backups/db/$(/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).sql.bak: Permission denied`

Comment: So, there two problems here, the first one being that you don't seem to have permission to create a file inside `/home/jordan/tutorialinux/backups/db/`, and the second that your `$(...)` substitution seems to be not working, which is nothing I've ever encountered.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have permissions to write to those directories too! Strange.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Starting to get there. After digging [https://serverfault.com/questions/387072/do-i-need-to-add-sudo-for-mysqldump-command-for-the-mysql-backup-script] I've discovered the output redirection is not running as root, but only the dump part, that's why it's returning the path after my output ">" character with a permission denied error.

Comment: Oh, I completely overlooked the fact that you were using `sudo`.  If you are logged in as "jordan" then just make `/home/jordan/tutorialinux/backups/db` writable to yourself, and you don't need elevated privileges for the output redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I created another user as me because I couldn't even get into mysql with root rights.

This helped. I made myself a new mysql user.

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> CREATE USER 'YOUR_SYSTEM_USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'YOUR_SYSTEM_USER'@'localhost';
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='auth_socket' WHERE User='YOUR_SYSTEM_USER';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

$ service mysql restart
```

That did not work with creating the dump but based on Micahel's advice I just changed permissions to the folder that was getting access denied errors so that it was writable to myself. Also made it readable to the user group.

```
chmod 740 jordan
chown jordan:jordan /home/jordan/tutorialinux/backups/db/
```

After that I could create the dump.